# Determine if Moya provider is stubbed or not

Tags: swift, rx-swift, moya

I stub my providers with a stub closure in my test target, but I want to determine if a given provider is stubbed or not.

```
let myProvider = RxMoyaProvider<MyAPI>(stubClosure: MoyaProvider.ImmediatelyStub)
```

but I can't get the stubClosure to tell me what StubBehaviour it's gonna return. Is there anyway to get the stubClosure for a given provider to tell me its return type?

Something like this.

```
switch(myProvider.stubClosure.??) {
    case StubBehavior.Immediate:
        // I'm a stubbed provider
    case StubBehaviour.Never:
        // I'm not a stubbed provider
}
```